# Binding Ninject depending on Controller requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding, ninject

I'm just learning Ninject and how to implement it in MVC situation. I'm trying to find out what the best way/practice is to setup the following scenario.

I have an Team Object, which will be reused through out the application, what I need to do is have Ninject resolve the binding automatically depending on where the request is coming from.

In my NinjectController factory I currently have a Service that resolves a Team to its proper repository

```
Bind<ITeamRepository>().To<SwimTeamRepository>() // non-space characters to enable edit submission
```

But if the request is coming in from SoccerController, I need to bind:

```
Bind<ITeamRepository>().To<SoccerTeamRepository>()
```

Should this be done conditionally, set up separate services? What is the best approach here? Or am I completely off the rail here...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you might be wanting to use [contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding). If that doesn't help, perhaps you could rephrase the question so I have a better idea of exactly what you're looking for.

This makes more sense after the edit. I'm not entirely sure how you have your application structured, but I would probably pass the ITeamRepository to the controller and the constructor would look something like this.

```
public SoccerController(ITeamRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}

public SwimmingController(ITeamRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```

And then the bindings:

```
Bind<ITeamRespository>().To<SoccerRepository>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SoccerController));
Bind<ITeamRespository>().To<SwimmingRepository>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SwimmingController));
```

Comment: Updated to reflect the latest version of Ninject and it's documentation on github. Thanks Ruben!

Comment: Thanks Timothy, this is almost exactly what I'm looking for, I wasn't sure though if this broke any good practices, as it seems that the binds are "hardcoded" of sort. But will this binding still work if for example I had a TeamList object that is initiated within each controller, so that if I pass in the SwimmingRepository it lists swimmers but if I pass in the SoccerRepository it lists soccer players?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Doesn't the data from the TeamList come from the repository? If so, it would be up to the implementation of SoccerRepository or SwimmingRepository to return the correct type?

Comment: Yes it does... I think I'm just spinning my wheels now... Time for a break. Thanks Timothy!

Answer (score 4):

[@Timothy Strimple's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915256/binding-ninject-depanding-on-controller-requests/5915357#5915357) is largely correct (hence my +1) except:

1. Its for Ninject v1 - the CodePlex site needs to disappear as everything now [lives on github](http://github.com/ninject)
2. you can express the fact that the binding to use is dependent on the controller involved via conditional binding -- [there's an example in the wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's much more elegant than the v1 version.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller's constructors you should pass in either an interface or abstract implementation of the type that Ninject will provide a concrete type for.

```
public SomeController(IRepositoryType repository) {
}
```

In the `NinjectControllerFactory` class you'll have the binding set up like this:

```
Bind.<IRepositoryType>()
    .To<DatabaseRepository>()
    ;
```

If your concrete implementation needs constructor arguments you can pass them in at the time they're bound.

```
Bind.<IRepositoryType>()
    .To<DatabaseRepository>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connStr",
        "some_connection_string_here"
    );
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.
        ;

Comment: ...and I just terminated my sentence with a semi-colon.  I need to get away from the desk a few minutes I think. =/

Comment: Lol I do that too, in emails and everything! Thanks for the response. This is what I'm looking for but sort of a more "dynamic" version